# Magento 1.9 - Cron not work when is uncommented

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have a problem about cron of Magento 1.9.2.4. The problem  is that the cron not running. I write in my .htaccess this line

```
Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
```

Cron charge immediately the blank page without bringing price updates and rules to the site.

I have already set my cron from cPanel, but still does not work. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dont use http://xxx.domain/cron.php to run it.

Set it in server crontab -e , run the cron.sh by command line.

Comment: Must i set only the cron.sh? Or i must set the cron.sh together with the cron.php?

Comment: should run the cron.sh, it contains some logic to run cron.php